# How can I update this MySQL query to get proper data?

Tags: mysql

**I have a table `my_table` look like -**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| phone               | status              |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 019                 | NI                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 019                 | DROP                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 019                 | SALE                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 018                 | B                   |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 016                 | DROP                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**My QUERY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(phone) AS phone FROM my_table WHERE status NOT IN ('NI','SALE','B')
```

**RESULT**

```
+---------------------+
| phone               |
+---------------------+
| 019                 |
+---------------------+
| 016                 |
+---------------------+
```

**But I want like below**

```
+---------------------+
| phone               |
+---------------------+
| 016                 |
+---------------------+
```

I don't want phone `019` in my query result. Because phone `019` have already `NI` and `SALE` status.

How can i do it by updating my query?

Comment: Are those the only two columns? You can't filter in any meaningful way to get the result that you want with just those columns.

Comment: No there are also many columns. But I want only `phone` fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use an *anti-join* pattern:

```
 SELECT t.phone
   FROM my_table t
   LEFT
   JOIN my_table r
     ON r.phone = t.phone
    AND r.status IN ('NI','SALE','B')
  WHERE r.phone IS NULL
 GROUP BY t.phone
```

Think of it this way.  We can get a list of all `phone` values...

And we can get a list of `phone` values that have a status 'NI', 'SALE' or 'B'.

The trick is returning values of `phone` from the "all" list excluding those that are in the second list.

The anti-join is just an option; there are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

---

Some other options are a NOT EXISTS subquery...

```
 SELECT t.phone
   FROM my_table t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                       FROM my_table r
                      WHERE r.phone = t.phone
                        AND r.status IN ('NI','SALE','B')
                   )
 GROUP BY t.phone
```

Another option is conditional aggregation...

```
 SELECT t.phone
   FROM my_table t
 GROUP BY t.phone
HAVING IFNULL(SUM(t.status IN ('NI','SALE','B')),0) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone
FROM yourtable AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM yourtable AS b
                   WHERE a.phone = b.phone
                     AND b.status in ('NI', 'SALES', 'B'));
```

This has the added benefit that it will always use indexes assuming there is one on phone.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the logic you want.

Here I go for phone who doesnt have `NI`, doesnt have `SALES` and doesnt have `B`.

```
 SELECT phone
 FROM my_table 
 GROUP BY phone
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'NI' THEN 1 END) = 0
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'SALES' THEN 1 END) = 0
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'B' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Phone `019` have 3 status `NI`,`DROP` and `SALE`. I want only `phone` which don't have status `NI`,`SALE`,`B`

Comment: Or, more succinctly...  `HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status IN ('NI','SALES','B') THEN 1 END) = 0` +10

Comment: @spencer7593 You are right, at first tought was an `OR` comparasion, and later change to `AND` and didnt saw that shortcut.

Comment: I updated my `Query` and posted the answer. This is working fine for me. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed my problem by updating my `Query`.**

**PROPER QUERY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(phone) FROM my_table WHERE status NOT IN ('NI','SALE','B') AND status IN ('DROP')
```

Above `query` is working for me, And execution time is reduced.